# Prestashop Fancybox JS cannot load correctly

Tags: javascript, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

i have some JS problems in my new Prestashop website.
Fancybox seems to create conflict.
This is the error in Chrome console

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (custom.js:216)
at u (core.js:39)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (core.js:39)
at Function.ready (core.js:39)
at HTMLDocument.H (core.js:39)
```

The website is [taglioestampa.it](http://taglioestampa.it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your theme do not use Fancybox.
so you need to include fancybox JS script.

it's located here :

so add before

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://taglioestampa.it/js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Hmm I tried but doesn't work, or maybe I've not understood what is exactly to do..sorry I'm new to JS.

Comment: in your template you need to find footer.tpl, i guess the </body> tag is in there

Comment: It worked! I added the line in layout-both-columns.tpl, there is the </body> tag.
thank you!